# Random process of the form $X(t)=A^t$ where $A$ is a given random variable

Tags: probability, proof-verification, random

We’re going to look at a random process, which is a sequence of random process, which is a sequence of random variables that depend on time. Let $X(t)=A^t$ where $A$ has the density $f_A (a)=(3/8) a^2$ for $0\le a\le 2$. Assume $t\ge 1$.

a) Find $F_X (x)$ and $f_X (x)$ (to get this, assume $t$ is fixed-so you can assume the $t$ is a constant).
b) If $t=2$ find $P(X>1)$.
c) Find $E(X)$

#### Progress

For a) I got $F_X(x)=(xt)^3/8-x^3/8$ from $0≤x≤(2/t)$ and $f_X (x)=(3/8)x^2t^3-(3/8)x^3$ and c) I got $3/2t-3/2t^4$. Are those right and what do I do for b)?

Here is my work for a.

$F_X (x)=P(X≤x)=P(A/t≤x)=P(A≤xt)$

$=∫_x^xt〖3/8) a^3 (da)=1/8 a^3 |_x^xt 〗$

$0≤a≤2→0≤xt≤2$

$=1/8 (xt)^3-1/8 x^3$

$0≤x≤2/t$

$f_x (x)=d/dx (F_x (x))$

$=3/8 x^2 t^3-3/8 x^2$

$0≤x≤2/t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $F_X$ is absurd since $X$ is a random process, not a random variable. For every $t$ and $x$ positive, $[X(t)\leqslant x]=[A^t\leqslant x]=[A\leqslant x^{1/t}]$ hence $F_{X(t)}(x)=F_A(x^{1/t})=\min\left\{1,\frac18x^{3/t}\right\}$. Equivalently, $F_{X(t)}(x)=0$ for every $x\leqslant0$, $F_{X(t)}(x)=\frac18x^{3/t}$ for every $0\leqslant x\leqslant2^t$ and $F_{X(t)}(x)=1$ for every $x\geqslant2^t$.

You might want to continue.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand your response fully. Can you expand on that a little?

Comment: Sure--as soon as you explain in detail the points you do not understand "fully" in it.

Comment: I follow up until you get the minimum after that I get confused on the operations you use to get the rest

Comment: ?? The part after "Equivalently" is a mere rephrasing of the "minimum" formula (and its trivial extension to negative arguments). Sorry but you lost me.

Comment: Yeah I get it now I got confused because I did some wrong operations early.